# How can I make a printable map for a spherical Earth globe?

Tags: gimp, paint.net

Preferably, with a non professional free software, such as Gimp or Paint.net.

In essence, I want to turn this: [image: this]

into this:[image: this]

- How can I portion the image in multiple pieces with the same area?
- How can I "pinch" the tips to make them smaller, like in the second pic?

I am using one of [these pictures from Nasa](https://visibleearth.nasa.gov/view_cat.php?categoryID=1484). Any better idea for my project is welcome.

(I don't want to use the second picture as it is because I want to use one with a good resolution.)

Answer (score 3):

With those programs... you can not.

Turning a flat projection into another flat projection, intended to be folded into a 3D solid requires some transformations that are not easily achievable.

There is a chance Hugin can make some of those transformations. I think it can turn that spherical projection into a cubical one, but I am not sure if you can choose another solid.

One option could be using Blender which is free.

1. Project the texture into a UV sphere.
2. Cut the seams.
3. Edit and peal methodically the vertexes into a flat arrangement.

But as you can see it is not a "non" professional work.

You can also try to model a 3D object and let this program to peal it for you https://tamasoft.co.jp/pepakura-en/

Some other options here: https://alternativeto.net/software/pepakura-designer/

<sub>P.S. Gimp and Paint net, or any program for that matter can be professionally used.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an article about this topic on my blog several years ago:

https://jumpjack.wordpress.com/2009/02/06/come-creare-un-mappamondo-globo-terrestre-3d-reale-in-plastica/

Since 2009 probably there are more options available, anyways here it is what I found at the time:

- [GIMP plugin](http://www.vendian.org/mncharity/dir3/planet_globes/TemporaryURL/make_globe_gore_map)
- [GIMP plugin 2](http://forum.cartographersguild.com/showpost.php?p=48106&postcount=4)
- ["Flexify", Irfanview/Photoshop plugin](http://www.flamingpear.com/flexify.html)
- "Slicer", Irfanview/Photoshop plugin: [slicer.afs](http://www.philohome.com/rhombicuboctahedron/slicer.afs) ,  [slicer.8bf](http://www.philohome.com/rhombicuboctahedron/slicer.8bf)
- Command line tool "[ppmglobe](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppmglobe.html)" (contained in NetPBM)
- [GlobeMaker](http://turnipsoft.com/jim/palaeogeography/globemaker.htm) (vb.net SW with sources)
- [Standalone PERL Script](http://www.vendian.org/mncharity/dir3/planet_globes/TemporaryURL/make_gores_pl.txt)
- [USGS Daisy-Petal creator (requires .NET 2.0)- Windows SW](http://www.winski.net/?page_id=7)
- [GMT – Generic Mapping Tools for Windows](http://gmt.soest.hawaii.edu/gmt4/gmt/gmt_windows_SOEST.html)
- [NASA g. projector](http://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/gprojector/download_win.html)

Comment: Some links are broken, and probably it is a good idea to link not the script itself, but a webpage explaining the plugin. When you open one of them, it shows code, but no explanations.

Comment: It seems that **ppmglobe** fits exactly to Eduardo needs. I suggest you ti edit your answer adding two example pictures.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of water has flown through the Strait of Messina since the question was new, but nothing worth of your acceptance has still appeared. Here's a new aspirant.

Making an actual globe map needs a substantial amount of handcrafting experience. In the next video a globemaker reveals some details of his process.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5N18eSMuDO8

Mathematicians say that no planar slices will bend exactly along a sphere, some squeezing or stretching is a must. The globemaker in the video says that he uses map slices which are printed a couple of percents too small. His gluing workflow stretches them just the right amount to fit. The slices do not have overlaps. The right squeezing percentage surely depends on the used materials, too. If the map paper happens to have somehow non-uniformly directed fibers the case can be complex. Unfortunately I do not know enough of it for any useful details.

Sorry for disturbing you beforehand with future difficulties. How to get those slices - that was the problem in the question. Let's write something for it.

The starting image you showed is an equirectangular earth map - a planar projection which is exact on the equator and stretches toward the poles to present spherical meridian-parallel rectangles as equally sized planar rectangles. Now you want to remap the equirectangular planar map to Gauss-Kruger style (still planar) slices.

As others have said years ago, common graphic programs do not have the the wanted transformation as one click effect. Someone has quite recently added a bunch of 3rd party software suggestions. Some of them may well be worth trying.

My suggestion belongs to the same class - to plugins. Krita, GIMP, Photoshop and Paint.NET have all freeware plugin named G'MIC effect collection. Its filter Deformations > Cartesian Transform converts easily a rectangular slice of your map to the wanted form. Unfortunately it's useful only for bitmap images.

Let's assume you have a high resolution starting image which has pixel dimensions say 3600 pixels wide and 1800 pixels high. The width must be twice the height because the globe equator is twice as long as the distance from pole to pole. I said 3600 x 1800 just to have simple looking numbers.It's up to you to decide the pixels per inch numbers so that the image has right dimensions as printed (including the room for paper stretching).

Let's assume you want twelve slices as you have inserted to the question. Then you divide the 3600x1800 px image to 12 vertical images, each of them is 300 x 1800 px. They can be as well separate image files as only selections.

Each image or selection gets the next Cartesian Transformation:
[image]

The equations x = w/2+(x-w/2)/(sin(y*pi/h)) ; y = y

are based on elementary geometry. They only squeeze the image horizontally so that the image width at different parallels becomes the same as the distance of corresponding meridians on the globe surface. High school level geometry knowledge is enough for writing the formulas from scratch.

The equations have the rectangular slice width and height as parameters w and h which get their values automatically from the image or selection size. The empty areas in the result are here defined to become transparent.

Someone may notice a division by zero at y=0 in the equation. The programmer has taken such possibilities into the account, so the filter does its job without stopping and returning an error message.

The slice is taken from your attached low resolution map, so the result isn't especially fine for high quality printing. NASA gives also some high resolution - even tens of thousands of pixels wide - images for free, but check the licensing to see if your intended usage is legal.

One can find discussions where people tried to make the same transformation by applying envelope or cage distortions. Such attempts are not mathematically sound like the shown Cartesian transformation, but they can be used for vector images and the accuracy can be good enough for some applications. I wouldn't try to make a globe map with them.

Comment: Your explanations are not perfect, no matter where you have published them earlier  Equirectangular plane projection of the earth DOES HAVE proportions W:H = 2:1 Otherwise one degree from east to west couldn't be on the planar map as long as one degree from north to south. Now you have got what's the math truth. Better late than never.

Comment: I'll take a deeper dive.

Comment: No problem. The essential thing here is that the given starting image (540 x 270 px) is an equirectangular planar projection of the earth. A cylindrical projection would have W:H = Pi. Check for ex. this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection. Unfortunately the only hard fact here is math.